# Radio Buttons not saving correct value in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

After a couple of tries on fixing my code, and searching for any solutions on the net, I finally gave up and would like to ask help on you guys.

I'm working on multiple sets of radio buttons and turn them to star ratings:

[imgur link on my ratings section (cause I am not able to post images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3pI6.png)

Each star is represented with 1 radio button, and each row has 5 radio buttons. In this image, im creating 3 sets of 5 radio buttons. Using the ng-repeat feature,

```
  <tr ng-repeat="number in called_numbers">
<td>             
    <div ng-if="number.name != null">
        <span class="star-rating" ng-init="temp_called_numbers[$index].rating.value ">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="temp_called_numbers[$index].rating.value" value="1"><i></i>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="temp_called_numbers[$index].rating.value" value="2"><i></i>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="temp_called_numbers[$index].rating.value" value="3"><i></i>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="temp_called_numbers[$index].rating.value" value="4"><i></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Now this specific page keeps on refreshing so when you click/highlight on a specific star, it refreshes and returns 5 blank stars again. What I did was that, I created an array to temporary store the value of each row.

```
$scope.temp_called_numbers = [];
$scope.rating_stars = {
        value:0
    };
```

and setting `$scope.temp_called_numbers` by:

```
rate_stars = function(){
        for(i=0; i < $scope.called_numbers.length; i++){
            $scope.temp_called_numbers.push( {rating: $scope.rating_stars});
        }

    }
```

The issue here now is that, when I select a star/radio button in one row, the other rows get the same value. For example, I select 1 star for row 1 which is `temp_called_numbers[0].rating.value` indexed 0, all the other rows get 1 star as well.

Any code change, reference or any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: instead of pushing (which will change the stored value) I would use angulat.extend to keep original properties and add new properties to the object. Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Comment: wow, seems like the extend feature was right. but will test a bit. thanks for that @Jax700303

Comment: popped my comment into an answer for clarity

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.temp_called_numbers = [];
$scope.rating_stars = {
        value:0
    };
rate_stars = function(){
    rating = $scope.rating_stars;
    for(i=0; i < $scope.called_numbers.length; i++){
        angular.extend(temp_called_numbers, rating);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="number in called_numbers">
<td>             
    <div ng-if="number.name != null">
        <span class="star-rating" ng-init="temp_called_numbers[$index].rating.value ">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="number.checked"><i></i>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="number.checked"><i></i>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="number.checked"><i></i>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="number.checked"><i></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>  
</tr>
```

// Access selected items

```
angular.forEach($scope.called_numbers, function(value, index) {
        if (value.checked) {
              $scope.called_numbers[index].checked = isSelectAll;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those checking on this thread. I've figure out that the issue here is not on the saving-to-array part, however, the issue is on the HTML side of the code.

Also, this was a visual bug on the stars and the array is fine and it stores the data when clicked. The reason that I was not getting the right data when clicking the radio button from 1 set of radio button group is because I was using `<span></span>` for the wrapper on the radio button.

what happened was that, even though I was getting 2 or more sets of Radio Button through `ng-repeat`, the page only accepts 1 radio button input.

By changing the wrapper to `<form></form>`:

```
<form class="star-rating" ng-init="temp_called_numbers[$index].rating.value ">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="number.checked"><i></i>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="number.checked"><i></i>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="number.checked"><i></i>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-model="number.checked"><i></i>
    </form>
```

I can now get 2 or more different inputs from each set of radio button group.